# Does the httpc:request option sync block?

Tags: erlang, httpc

```
httpc_request(Url) ->
    HttpOpts = [{timeout, 5000}],
    Opts = [{sync, true}, {full_result, false}, {body_format, binary}],   
    httpc:request(get, {Url, []}, HttpOpts, Opts).
```

In gen_server process p(pid = P), execute function `httpc_request(Url)`, I find some process maybe block in httpc:handle_answer receive

`process_info(P, current_function)` shows the result:

```
{current_function,{httpc,handle_answer,3}}
```

`ets:match_object(httpc_manager__handler_db, {_='_', _='_', P})` shows the result:

```
[{Ref,HandlePid,P}]
```

`process_info(HandlePid, [current_function, status])` shows the result:

```
[{current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}},{status,waiting}]
```

process P is use receive to wait for HandlePid reply, but HandlePid is in gen_server loop wait for receive tcp packet. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Unless you've got a compelling reason to use `httpc`, don't. It doesn't get a lot of love from the OTP team, and you might be better off using a third-party library. I prefer hackney, but there are others.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `httpc` for this... I've used [gun](https://github.com/ninenines/gun) a few times in conjunction with a gen_server without any problems.